# Javascript weird if else not working

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Anyone knows why showToast always pops up even if desiredquantity is greater than inventoryCount?

```
  function checkavailable(){
  var desiredquantity = document.getElementById("bin-Qty").value;
  var inventoryCount = document.getElementById("bin-binItem-quantity").value;
  var itemName = document.getElementById("bin-binItem").value;
  if(desiredquantity > inventoryCount)
  {
    console.log(desiredquantity);
    showToast('There are only ' +inventoryCount +' '+itemName+' left');
  }
  else
  {
    addToTransfer();
  }
}
```

I have a button to that calls checkavailable

```
<button type="button"
   onclick ="checkavailable();">
</button>
```

Comment: Convert the values read from DOM to Number. You can use `Number`, `parseFloat`, `parseInt`, Unary Plus, etc. Ex: `parseInt(document.getElementById("bin-Qty").value, 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please convert it to number first

Like this

```
if (+desiredquantity > +inventoryCount) { // + will parse it as number
  console.log(desiredquantity);
  showToast('There are only ' + inventoryCount + ' ' + itemName + ' left');
} else {
  addToTransfer();
}
```

Or you can use **[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** if value is integer and if value float than use **[`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)**

Like this

```
if (parseInt(desiredquantity) > parseInt(inventoryCount)) {
  console.log(desiredquantity);
  showToast('There are only ' + inventoryCount + ' ' + itemName + ' left');
} else {
  addToTransfer();
}
```